# how to dynamically change the content of modal on an Image click

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have the following 3 thumbnail images on an HTML page. When the user clicks on any of these images,  I want to show that particular image in a modal.

How can I dynamically pass the image name inside the modal-body, on every image click?

```
<a href="images/Picture1.jpg" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  <img src="images/Picture1.jpg" alt="image not available" onclick=check(this)>
</a>
<a href="images/Picture2.jpg" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  <img src="images/Picture2.jpg" alt="image not available" onclick=check(this)>
</a>
<a href="images/Picture3.jpg" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  <img src="images/Picture3.jpg" alt="image not available" onclick=check(this)>
</a>
```

Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Image</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="images/Picture1.jpg" alt="image not available" id="imagepreview" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Js function which tells, which image is clicked

```
function check(img) {
  var src = img.src.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, "");
  console.log(src);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the `src` attribute of the image in your modal-body with the one of the image which was clicked.

Each image has `onclick=check(this)`. It means that the function `check` will receive as a parameter the `img` element that was clicked.

You can select the image in your modal thanks to its `id` by using [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and update the `src` of the modal image with the `src` of the `img` element in parameter.

```
function check(img) {
  document.getElementById("imagepreview").src = img.src;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can not catch you. How do I replace the  `src` attribute of the image in modal-body?

Comment: @Meana I updated my answer to explain how. But the answer of your question is litteraly the only line of the function check in the code snippet I provided.